# Как выбрать записи сделанные за последнюю минуту?

Tags: django, django-orm

Предположим есть класс:

```
class A(models.Model)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Как сделать запрос, чтобы выбрать записи за последнюю минуту?

Comment: Уточните, запрос вы будете делать средствами SQL или в том же Django/Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

last_minute = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=1)
results = A.objects.filter(create_time__gt=last_minute)
```